# How convert this jquery object

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello I use the jquery library for the first time.

**Jquery**:

```
function habdleProductSubmitRequest(event) {
            //no reload page
            event.preventDefault()
var productId = $(this).find('[name="id"]').val();
var productName = $(this).find('[name="name"]').val();
var productPrice = $(this).find('[name="price"]').val();

$.ajax({
    url:'/api/ajaxrest/post' ,
    method: 'POST',
    processData: false,
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify({
        id: productId,
        name: productName,
        price : productPrice
    }),
    complete: function(result){

        console.debug(result)

        $('#result3').text(result);


    }

})

}
```

**form**

```
<h2>Add a new task</h2>

<form
        class="datatable__row datatable__row--add"
        method="POST"
        action="http://localhost:8080/v1/task/createTask"
        data-product-add-form=""

>
    <fieldset class="datatable__row-section datatable__row-section--input-section">
        <label class="datatable__input-label">
            Product Id
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="id" placeholder="Insert a task name" th:required="required" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="datatable__row-section datatable__row-section--input-section">
        <label class="datatable__input-label">
            Task name
        </label>
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Insert a task name" th:required="required" />
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="datatable__row-section datatable__row-section--input-section">
        <label class="datatable__input-label">
            Task content
        </label>
        <textarea name="price" placeholder="Insert task content" th:required="required"></textarea>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset class="datatable__row-section datatable__row-section--button-section">
        <button type="submit" data-task-add-button="" class="datatable__button">Add a task</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<fieldset>
    <span id="result3"></span>
</fieldset>
```

I do not know how to display this returned object. This function does not display me in the view of this object

```
$('#result3').text(object);
```

I tried:

```
$('#result3').text(object.name + object.price);
```

but displayed nothnig. so I checked this object using consol.debuger  [and here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Gmd6.png)

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. Could you please edit the question to include more details about what `object` is, and what output you want to achieve

Comment: What to you want to display? Can you give us an example of what you want according to what you show us please?

Comment: It seems that the `object` is actually `ajax` object. The API of `text` is to pass `string` to it. Can you show us how do you get this `object` (Just show all the relevant code).

Comment: Also, which part of the result do you want to display? (e.g. `id`? `name`?)

Comment: for example name

Answer (score 1):

There is no `name` nor `price` on that `object`. It says so on your screen-shot. There is however `responseJSON`, with `name` and `price`. So why not use those? (*I also added space between the two, but you should format those as you like/need*)

```
$('#result3').text(object.responseJSON.name + " " + object.responseJSON.price);
```